# Cannot testfor from specific coordinates

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I can't get `/testfor` to work on a certain coordinate but I can get it to work within a radius. What am i doing wrong?

```
/testfor @a[x=1074 y=4 z=919 r=10]
```

Answer (score 3):

Selector arguments are separated by commas, not spaces. Try:

```
/testfor @a[x=1074,y=4,z=919,r=10]
```

If you turn on the command block's output (change the `X` button to an `O`), it will often give useful error messages.